# What is the classification of the two Star Destroyers over Scarif?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

Towards the end of Rogue one, we see the Rebel Fleet, led by a Dauntless, engage two Star Destroyers over Scarif. Now, when I first watched the movie, I was under the distinct impression that these were two Victory-Class Star Destroyers. However, seeing Q&As on this site and others, most people seem to think that these were Imperial-I class Star Destroyers, the same as Vader’s flagship when he jumps into the fray near the end of the battle (and absolutely cleans up).

**Can someone confirm the classification of these two destroyers?**

Comment: Hmmm. Aren’t *Victory*-class Star Destroyers Legends?

Comment: The game Star Wars: Battlefront names them as Imperial I-Class Star Destroyers; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Scarif#cite_note-Battlefront-2

Comment: @Adamant ah, you know they may just be. I know we've seen the Acclamator cruiser in Disney canon (seen in Star Wars Rebels) but I am not sure we have seen a victory-class in canon (unless it's in rogue one)

Comment: @Adamant I asked a related question to that question - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/148003/11841

Comment: @enderland Thank you for the question, that confirms the canonicity of the Victory Class.

Comment: @DBPriGuy While I understand your statement "Disney canon" to mean "things created post Disney sale" actual Disney Canon includes both The Clone Wars (which has the Acclamator) and the prequel trilogy as well.

Comment: @Mark: ah yes, true, for some reason I saw the Imperial Acclamator as distinct from the Republic Acclamator but I suppose they really are the same thing

Comment: Well, both of these destroyers looked like the one Vader commanded. You could argue that his ship "cleaned it up" immediatly as opposed to the other two for several reasons. The Rebel Fleet engaged two destroyers at full strength and disabled one of them very quickly. The other was hopelessly outnumbered but did some serious damage before being destroyed. Devastator jumped in when the Rebel Fleet was charging hyperdrives (which always seems to make ships vulnerable), and attacked ships that probably had little shields and were already seriously beaten up after a very difficult battle.

Comment: @Petersaber I dare to say that it wasnt quick....they only disabled it after someone destroyed its sphere on top and by then all ships int he rebel fleet had already sustained quite some damage. (the command ship with 50% shields left)

Comment: @Thomas only reinforcing the idea that Devastator cleaned up because it was at 100% strenght and Rebel ships were really beaten up. And let's face it, at least one ship just crashed into Darth Vader's ship

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dunno how this doesn't have a good answer yet but here goes: the star destroyers over Scarif are Imperial I-Class Star Destroyers. You can tell because of the Tractor Beam array over the conning tower/bridge area. Impstar Deuces have a lateral bar over that section of the bridge - one of the main visual differences to key on. As you can see from the attached image below of these particular SDs
[image: Star Destroyers over Scarif]
You can see the design for the Tractor Beam Array here: [image]

The Impstar Deuce looks like this: [image: Impstar Deuce]

Further they are not Victory Class star destroyers - those have the tell tale flaps on the side and are about 700 Meters smaller than the impressive 1600 M length of Imperial I-Class SDs.

Lastly and for bonus points, the Star Destroyer that Vader arrives on is the *Devastator* an Imperial I-Class SD

All Disney canon: blueprint from the Star Wars Rebels chapter book Droids in Distress

Answer (score -1):

Only from watching the film I couldn't glean any visual difference between Vaders star destroyer and the other two that the rebel fleet fought against. As they look the same and also sizewise they seemed similar it is 90% likely that they are also imperial star destroyers. As far as I'm aware vaders ship was a ISD-I so they will probably be no better ships there (aka ISD-II).

One point also confused me while I watched the film....why were the rebels able to destroy these TWO ships so easily and got outright destroyed by the third one. That is until I mulled over the whole battle. The rebels had lost a few smaller ships to the star destroyers during it AND what is more important even their fleet hq ship took quite a beating. And that is the most important thing here.
Its shield even before the star destroyers were destroyed were 50% and less!

So if we take into account that most of the rebel fleet already jumped away when vader came.....he hit a few of the ships with their shields probably down (or weakened) due to the impending hyperjump and no further enemy ships in the area and because of the beating they took before.....which COULD explain the one shot destruction hits of the nebulon Bs. The shields being severly damaged already also explains why the rebel fleet hq went down so quickly to a single star destroyer...in addition to the important part that there were WAY less targets remaining that could soak the hits the star destroyer dished out.

Thus all in all....if the other 2 ships hadnt been there before...vaders ship would probably have been destroyed (not taking his own tie fighter skills into account). It only gained the upper hand so quickly thanks to most of the rebels already having went away and the other ships being badly damaged already.

Also this means that if vaders ship had been there from the beginning it COULD have been that the imperials had won the initial fight. Although it is not assured as we don't know how much firepower went away with the ships that had jumped out of system already when Vader came.

So all in all (from the film): It is extremely likely that the two star destroyers are imperial 1 star destroyers. The same as Vaders ship.

Comment: I assumed Vader was on the Executor, but I did not get a good look at the ship

Comment: No it was a normal star destroyer and no super one. in fact it is the same one that appeared at the beginning of episode 4

Comment: For the -1 it is always nice to know why ^^