# What Star Destroyer classes exist in Disney canon?

Tags: star-wars

Within Legends, there are many different Star Destroyer classes - Victory, Interdictor, multiple Imperial class, Super Star Destroyers, etc.

What models are present in the new Disney canon?

Comment: Interdictor has been seen in Star Wars: Rebels, so that one is officially canon now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### *Venator*-class

[These](http://www.starwars.com/databank/imperial-star-destroyer) are the Star Destroyers used in the Clone Wars, seen in the *Clone Wars* animated series and *Revenge of the Sith*.

[image]

### *Victory*-class

Mentioned in the canon novel *Tarkin*:

> Originally a cramped garrison base deployed from a *Victory*-class Star destroyer, Sentinel now sprawled in all directions as a result of prefabricated modules that had since been delivered or assembled on site.
>
> <sup>*Tarkin* Chapter 2: "Blows Against the Empire"</sup>

### *Secutor*-class

Also mentioned in *Tarkin*:

> The *Secutor*-class Star Destroyer *Conquest* hung in fixed orbit above the Carida Imperial Navy Deepdock Facility Two, some half a million kilometers from the eponymous planet.
>
> <sup>*Tarkin* Chapter 21: "Dissolution"</sup>

### *Tector*-class

Identified in the short story "The Levers of Power":

> Other Star Destroyers in the Imperial line had suffered far worse damage — the *Vehement* and the *Tector*-class *Harbinger* had been destroyed
>
> <sup>*Rise of the Empire* "The Levers of Power"</sup>

### *qaz*-class

Mentioned in the canon novel *Catalyst*:

> Krennic inclined his head in acknowledgment. "Preliminary results indicate that the energy released during the test-fire had the destructive power of the combined batteries of a *qaz*-class Star Destroyer."
>
> <sup>*Catalyst: A Rogue One Novel* Chapter 22: "Exit Wounds"</sup>

### *Imperial*-class

The class mostly seen in the original trilogy films. We know they still come in two varities, *Imperial* I-class and *Imperial* II-class, at least since the canon comic series *Shattered Empire*:

[image]

> **Shara Bey:** I've got an *Imperial*-class Star Destroyer at two-two mark six...looks like a deuce.
>
> <sup>*Shattered Empire* 3</sup>

### Super Star Destroyer

Clearly, the [Super Star Destroyer](http://www.starwars.com/databank/super-star-destroyer), seen in *Empire Strikes Back* and *Return of the Jedi*, remains canon.

### *Resurgent*-class

Used by the First Order:

> Almost invisible when they first dropped from a port in the side of the immense *Resurgent*-class Star Destroyer, the four transport vessels were of a proven design.
>
> <sup>*The Force Awakens* Chapter 1</sup>

### Interdictor cruisers

Although they're not considered Star Destroyers, it's worth remarking that *Tarkin* introduces three separate varieties of Interdictor ships:

> [P]ositioned against a radiant sweep of stars, floated three Interdictor vessels, a Detainer CC-2200, a newer model CC-7700 frigate, and—fresh from deepdock in the Corellia system and as yet untested—an Immobilizer 418.
>
> <sup>*Tarkin* Chapter 17: "Zero Defects"</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**Xyston-class**

The Xyston-class star destroyer, also known as the Sith Star Destroyer, is also in canon. See Wookieepedia for more information. [starwars.fandom.com/wiki/xyston-class_star_destroyer](http://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/xyston-class_star_destroyer)

Comment: these ships appeared in the Rise Of Skywalker, and were based off of the Imperial-class

Comment: To make this a good answer you should include a link in your answer that demonstrates their appearance in RoS.